# Subquery in count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying a subquery where I get all the duplicate accounts with different owners. But I get an error on line 4, I don't know what I can do or what method you recommend. For example, this table shows how the results should be displayed.

| ACCOUNTS | OWNERS |
| --- | --- |
| 204060 | HUGO TORREZ |
| 204060 | LUIS FLORES |
| 32565963 | ERICK LIRA |
| 32565963 | NOE PRIETO |

```
SELECT issuing_account, COUNT(1)
FROM TBL_TXN
WHERE 1 = 1 group by issuing_account
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
(SELECT DISTINCT OWNERS
                  FROM TBL_TXN
            WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE='B');
```

Comment: You have written one query ending on `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`. Then you have added another query in parentheses after that. Just glueing queries together like that don't work. Same in English: what would "select one result set (select another result set)" even mean?

Comment: What I gather from your description is this: There can be many rows per account in the table. For some accounts these rows all have the same owner, for other accounts they have different owners. You want to select the latter accounts along with their different owners. But how does the transaction type come into play?

Comment: `COUNT(1)` is a strange habit in my opinion by the way. If you want to count rows, count rows: `COUNT(*)`. If you want to count expressions except for nulls, count expressions `COUNT( expression )`. But don't count rows with a constant expression like `COUNT(1)`, `COUNT(123)` or `COUNT('count this row')`. (If the DBMS didn't optimize this into a simple `COUNT(*)`, this would even become costly.)

Comment: Use a window function `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OWNERS)`

Answer (score 1):

It would have been better if you posted some sample data (along with desired result) because - without that - we can only try to guess what you have.

Here's my guess: if there can be several owners per issuing account, *aggregate* them (using `listagg` function).

Subquery you wrote is misplace; I presume it should be a data source (inline view, in this case - could've been a CTE as well).

Something like this:

```
select issuing_account,
       listagg(owners, ', ') within group (order by null) owners,
       count(*)
from (select distinct owners, issuing_accounts
      from tbl_txn
      where transaction_type = 'B'
     )
group by issuing_account
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: The length in the concatenation was exceeded, and it does not give results. What I'm looking for is to bring duplicate accounts, but with different owners.

Comment: As I said, consider posting sample data. Also, desired result (you already posted) contains two columns: issuing account and owner, but query you posted contains issuing account and **count** function - these two don't match. It is kind of difficult to answer such questions. Try to provide as many details as necessary so that someone might assist.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know how to do my query correctly, but what I'm looking for is to bring duplicate accounts, but only those that have a different owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below queries,

If your account and owners are same you can group by both the columns,

```
SELECT issuing_account, owners, COUNT(1)
FROM TBL_TXN WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE='B'
group by issuing_account, owners having count(1) >1;
```

If account and owners are different, you can use rank to identify the duplicates with respect to account alone along with owner information,

```
SELECT issuing_account, owners FROM 
(SELECT issuing_account, owners, row_number() over(partition by issuing_account) as rnk
FROM TBL_TXN WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE='B') T1
WHERE rnk > 1;
```

Comment: The expected result is all duplicate accounts that have a different owner. As in the example of my table.

Comment: ```SELECT issuing_account, owners FROM 
(SELECT issuing_account, owners, row_number() over(partition by issuing_account) as rnk
FROM TBL_TXN WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE='B') T1
WHERE rnk > 1;```  This query should help you.